# Cannot receive emails from Debian server

Tags: php, email, debian

I have an issue regarding debian server. The same code I uploaded on cloud server and the contact form (with php) is working properly and is sending email.

I tested exactly the same code in our server in the office with Debian and it does not shows any error but we could not accept emails from contact form.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't send emails from local server directly
You can take a look at this question

[Send email from localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800492/setting-up-a-ubuntu-apache-php-machine-to-send-email)

localhost term means it's not equipped with mail capability
even though you can try this code to know if it has built in mail server or not

```
if (mail('email address','subject','message') === true){
     echo 'SENT';
}else{
    echo 'NOT SENT';
}
```