# Sending mail from linux server using php script

Tags: php, linux

I need to send a mail from my linux server using php script. Need help regarding this issue as i am novice to this concept.Thanks in advance.

> index.php

```
    <?php 
require_once "Mail.php";
$from = " <onik@opsonin.net>"; 
$to = "<onik@opsonin.net>"; 
$subject = "Hi!"; 
$body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

$host = "ssl://192.168.10.9"; 
$port = "25";
$username = "smtp_username"; 
$password = "smtp_password";

$headers = array 
('From' => $from,  
'To' => $to,   
'Subject' => $subject
);
$smtp = Mail::factory
('smtp',   array ('host' => $host,     'port' => $port,     'auth' => true,     'username' => $username,     'password' => $password));  $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body); 
if (PEAR::isError($mail)) 
{  
echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>"); 
} 
else { 
echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>"); 
} 
?>
```

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: Use PHP's mail() function.

Comment: You can use PHP' mail function or else you can use https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer php Mailer Library...

Comment: I have tried with php mail. i have edited my comment section with the tried code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting up a Ubuntu/Apache/PHP machine to send email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800492/setting-up-a-ubuntu-apache-php-machine-to-send-email)

Answer (score -1):

If your code is correct then it might be a server configuration issue.

Use the below simple steps to configure sendmail (answer Yes to everything)

```
sudo apt-get install sendmail
sudo sendmailconfig
sudo service apache2 restart
```