# php mail() not sending mail or returning error message, worked on my system (localhost) but not on ubuntu/apache2

Tags: php, apache, email, ubuntu

So I have a simple php file that gets data from a form and is supposed to email me. It works on my own system when I was testing it on localhost. But, when I deployed it on ubuntu using apache2, it didn't work. the file may not be pretty, my first attempt to email with php, but i've included the php file below. I know it gets to the mail() method and fails, it activates the (!$mail) conditional, but I can't ever print $mail or any errors so I have no clue what is wrong. any ideas? The cluster of echoes was my attempt to print some kind of error message with no luck. Also, I actually send it to my email address, I just changed it for this example

```html
<?php

if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){
  
  echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}

$visitor_name = $_POST['name'];
$visitor_message = $_POST['message'];

//incase the email isn't provided
if(empty($_POST['email'])){
  $visitor_email = 'n/a';
} else {
  $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
}

//incase the phone isn't provided
if(empty($_POST['phone'])){
  $visitor_phone = 'n/a';
  } else {
    $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
  }

  //incase the phone isn't provided
  if(empty($_POST['phone'])){
    $visitor_phone = 'n/a';
  } else {
    $visitor_phone = $_POST['phone'];
  }


  if(empty($visitor_name) || empty($visitor_message))
  {
    echo "Name and message are mandatory!";
    exit;
  }
  //a function created below for security purposes
if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
{
    echo "Bad email value!";
    exit;
}

// **************************** CODE FOR EMAIL BODY BELOW *****************************************

$email_body = '<html><body>';
$email_body .= "<h2> You've recieved a new message from: $visitor_name, they need a building </h2>";
$email_body .= '<h4> Here is the message: </h4>';
$email_body .= "<p> $visitor_message </p>";
$email_body .= "<h4> Their contact info is below</h4>";
$email_body .= "<ul> <li> email: $visitor_email </li>";
$email_body .= "<li> phone: $visitor_phone </li></ul>";
$email_body .= '</body></html>';


// **************************** END OF CODE FOR EMAIL BODY ****************************************



$to = 'j@example.com';
$subject = "Building Form Submission: $visitor_name Needs a building\r\n";
$headers = "From: building-form@ArchitectureAdvertisingWebsite.com \r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";

$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";


if($visitor_email != 'n/a'){
  $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
}


$mail = mail($to, $subject, $email_body, $headers);
print_r ($mail);
echo "end test";
if (!$mail){
  echo "Message not sent, there was an error. Please contact Jerrod at .....";
  $errorMessage = error_get_last();
  echo "There was an error: $errorMessage";
  echo "Below the error is printed : ";
  print_r(error_get_last());
} else {
  echo "Message sent";
  header('Location: end.html');
}


// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)'
              );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return true;
  } 
  else
    {
    return false;
  } 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emails sent directly by a PHP script in this way typically get marked as junk or spam by the major email providers. If you start sending them in any quantity, your email address (and possibly domain) will end up on Spamhaus and other blacklists.

If you need to send individualized emails like your example above, consider using a service like [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/) or [Amazon Simple Email Service](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/).

Comment: the problem is that it's not being sent at all

Comment: Is it your own server (local or virtual) or are you on a shared hosting environment?

Comment: it worked on my own server (localhost), but the issue is on aws ubuntu with apache2

Comment: You need to consider sendmail on your aws instance. Use the answer from @drew010 at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800492/setting-up-a-ubuntu-apache-php-machine-to-send-email

Comment: That was exactly what I needed, it works now. Nowhere did I see that you needed that installed for aws, now I just have to make sure it doesn't go to the spam/junk box, but it sounds like he's pointing me in the right direction